# attaching URL to a jquery function

Tags: jquery, scrollto, deep-linking

I have created a system with jquery.mousewheel and scrollTo that scrolls 800 pixels every time I move my mousewheel. The browsing is similar to this site: http://beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA8#sound-experience

My current code looks like this:

```
    var position = 1;
var rotation= true;
var ezin= 'easeInOutExpo';



if (position==1){
    $.scrollTo('0px', 100, { axis:'y',easing: ezin });
    $('.variable').text("1");
}


function DEL1AL2(){
    rotation= false;
    $('.variable').text("2");
    $.scrollTo('800px', 800, { axis:'y',easing: ezin, onAfter: function() {rotation= true; position=2;} });     
}

function DEL2AL1(){
    rotation= false;
    $('.variable').text("1");
    $.scrollTo('0px', 800, { axis:'y',easing: ezin, onAfter: function() {rotation= true; position=1;} });   
}

function DEL2AL3(){
    rotation= false;
    $('.variable').text("3");
    $.scrollTo('1600px', 800, { axis:'y',easing: ezin, onAfter: function() {rotation= true; position=3;} });
}

function DEL3AL2(){
    rotation= false;
    $('.variable').text("2");
    $.scrollTo('800px', 800, { axis:'y',easing: ezin, onAfter: function() {rotation= true; position=2} });
    ;
}

$(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0 && rotation==true){
        if(position==2){
            DEL2AL1();
        };
        if(position==3){
            DEL3AL2();
        };          
    }
    else if (delta < 0 && rotation==true){
        if(position==1){
            DEL1AL2();
        };
        if(position==2){
            DEL2AL3();
        };
    };      
    event.preventDefault();     
});});
```

The system has a numeric variable attached, so when you are in position 1 and scroll down, the function scrolls down 800 pixels and changes the position variable to 2.

How would you do it to add deep linking (I think that is the term), so when the position is 2 the URL reflects it (www.myexample.com/#2 for example), and so the link actually takes you to this second position?

The only reason I'm trying to do this is because I want different positions of the page to have their own facebook likes (portfolio items), if this deep linking is unnecessary and there's a better method to accomplish that I'm all ears.

Also, if you see any mistake in my current code please let me know, I'm learning slowly and anything I could polish is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically, anchor scrolling?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm going to look into that. Being a novice means sometimes I cannot find tutorials because I don't know the terms.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the window location when you arrive to a certain position:

```
var baseLocation = window.location;

function DEL1AL2(){
    rotation= false;
    $('.variable').text("2");
    $.scrollTo('800px', 800, { axis:'y',easing: ezin, onAfter: function() {rotation= true; position=2;} });     
    window.location = baseLocation+'#2';
}
```

and then when you load the page you can do something like:

```
   $(window).ready(function(){

    if (window.location.hash){
         // ...code to check what's the position that corresponds to the hash link.
        if (window.location.hash=='2'){ DEL1AL2();}
        // ...etc
    });
});
```

Comment: Will try it as soon as I can, from the looks I think it could work. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I'm using `window.location.hash = 'products';` to add the location in every DELxALy function, and it works, but I can't seem to find a way to trigger a function depending on the current url, tried with

`$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if (window.location.hash=='products'){
  DEL1AL2();
    };
});`

but it doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong here?

Also, is there a way to beautify the URL? I'm currently getting /mousescroll.htm#products, when I'd rather get /products or /#products

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smooth scrolling animation when scrolling to a specific element, you can check out the folowing plugin:

http://flesler.blogspot.be/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

This plugin allows you to scroll to a certain location based on:

- A raw number
- A string('44', '100px', '+=30px', etc )
- A DOM element (logically, child of the scrollable element)
- A selector, that will be relative to the scrollable element
- The string 'max' to scroll to the end.
- A string specifying a percentage to scroll to that part of the container (f.e: 50% goes to to the middle).
- A hash { top:x, left:y }, x and y can be any kind of number/string like above.

Comment: I'm using that plugin, notice the $.scrollTo... parts in the code :)

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what the actual problem is. You can pass an element to `scrollTo` (or a selector that results in an element), and the plugin will scroll to that given element. Could you please elaborate what else is needed?